# Cambiar consulta de mysql con javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysqli

Tengo un problema y no se como resolverlo a continuación muestro mi código de un select cargados con datos de mysql,

```
     <?php 
  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
  mysqli_select_db($link, "stp17");
  $tildes = $link->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); //Para que se muestren las tildes correctamente


  $resulta = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM estados where nombre='$nombreDelegacion'");

    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resulta)){

      $claveEstado=$fila['clave'];

    }

  $resultas = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM rutas WHERE (cveorig='$claveEstado' OR cvedest='$claveEstado') AND cliente='CLI140002'");?>

  <div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon">Ruta: </span>
      <select name="rutas" id="estados" value="0" class="form-control" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
        <?php
          while ($fil = mysqli_fetch_array($resultas)){  ?>

            <option value="<?php echo $fil['id']; ?>"><?php echo $fil['descripcion']; ?></option>

          <?php    } ?>
        </select>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
      <a href="rutas/nuevaRuta.php" class="btn btn-success" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></a>
  </span>
  </div>
```

Lo que desero hacer es cambiar el query que lo tengo asi

```
$resultas = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM rutas WHERE (cveorig='$claveEstado' OR cvedest='$claveEstado') AND cliente='CLI140002'");?>
```

A un query asi:

```
$resultas = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM rutas");
```

Todo esto dando click en un checkbox, al tenerlo seleccionado me muestra el segundo query y al no tenerlo seleccionado me muestra el primer query

Comment: javascript está de lado del cliente, no puedes hacer esto a menos que uses AJAX

Answer (score 1):

Si usas la opción de recargar tu página puedes hacer que el formulario se redirecciona así mismo y use el método `POST`, ya luego recuperas los valores en `PHP`.

En el siguiente código concateno la cadena en caso el `checkbox` está seleccionado; para tu caso sería el script.

```
<?php
$cadena = "Hola";
$selecionado = "";

if(!empty($_POST) && isset($_POST["control"])){ 
    $cadena .= " Mundo";    
    $selecionado = "checked";
}
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form id="idFormulario" method="POST">
    <h5><?php echo $cadena; ?></h5>

    <input id="control" name="control" type="checkbox" <?php echo $selecionado; ?>>     
</form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var form = document.getElementById('idFormulario');

    document.getElementById('control').addEventListener('change', function () {                 
        form.submit();
    });
</script>
</html>
```

**Ejemplo:**

[image: Ejemplo de seleccionar un checkbox]

---

*Como lees en los comentarios, puedes usar AJAX que no permitirá un recargo de la página.*